# MSSQL Невозможно задать ValidationStatus для внешних элементов при миграции на Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-websites

В процессе миграции базы на azure получаю ошибку "Невозможно задать ValidationStatus для внешних элементов. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)". Совершенно обычная база, никаких внешних юзеров нет

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась указанием владельца для БД (свойства/вкладка файл)